# Quick nth-child issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've a quick `:nth-child` issue that I'm struggling to solve. I'm aiming to target every 3rd and 4th item in a grouping of 4 items that form a list.

For example:

```
<div class="normal">Item 1</div>
<div class="normal">Item 2</div>
<div class="different">Item 3</div>
<div class="different">Item 4</div>
<div class="normal">Item 5</div>
<div class="normal">Item 6</div>
<div class="different">Item 7</div>
<div class="different">Item 8</div>
```

In this example I'd like to target all instances of `<div class="different">` - i've used a lot of nth-child generators to come up with an answer but nothing gets me to what I need.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: are they contained within a parent div?

Comment: $('.different') doesn't this work?

Comment: @DawoodAwan I think this is just for the example and he doesn't want to use a class

Comment: Can you post the previous solutions you've tried so far?

Comment: I was using the classes to highlight the problem, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `div:nth-child(4n-1), div:nth-child(4n)`. The logic is simple — you want to select items in **groups of four**, so `4n` would be the common denominator. Since you want to select the penultimate and the last items in the group, `4n-1` and `4n` respectively would do the job.

As follow is a simple diagram illustrating my point:

```
#1
#2
#3  <- 4th item - 1
#4  <- 4th item
#5
#6
#7  <- 4th item -1
#8  <- 4th item
```

```css
div:nth-child(4n-1), div:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">Item 1</div>
<div class="normal">Item 2</div>
<div class="different">Item 3</div>
<div class="different">Item 4</div>
<div class="normal">Item 5</div>
<div class="normal">Item 6</div>
<div class="different">Item 7</div>
<div class="different">Item 8</div>
```

Comment: This question comes up fairly often, but what doesn't come up fairly often is an explanation of how it works.

Comment: @BoltClock I hope my explanation is sufficient? If not, feel free to supplement it :)

Comment: @Alex Char: See Thomas's comment on the question.

Comment: @AlexChar: I was using classes to highlight the problem.